# Protecting high-capacity inverters

Tags: inverter

We have a 5 KVA home inverter. The weather, winds and rains, often causes power outages and fluctuations.
Our problem is mostly with the surge has damaged our inverters a few times the most recent being this week.
Aren't modern inverters supposed to be capable of handling surges/over-loads?

- How does one protect the inverter?
- Should we get a stabilizer for the inverter?
- If we should get a stabilizer, what should be the rating for the stabilizer?

Comment: You would probably want surge protector/s.  Either plug ins or whole house type.  Most hydro/power companies recommend turning off and/or unplugging most electrical appliances during storms/power outages to protect from surges/brownouts when power comes back.  Most electronics can be damaged by surges, some more than others.

Comment: You're not telling us much about your setup, you may be thinking "everyone with an inverter has the same setup we do" but *definitely not at all*.  I'm afraid any answers are going to be wild guesses until you tell us more about your setup.  You can [edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 5):

The inverter is designed for normal power it sounds like you have abnormally high power issues.

Adding a large whole home surge protector is about all you can do. Your inverter protects itself (by programmed values for shutdown on low voltage or from overloads).
Surges from weather events require additional protection.

Some surges are from lightning strikes , others are from switch gear changing feeds or recloser units detecting line shorts so they open and close usually 3 bumps and open to protect the lines. These bumps create massive power spikes or surges that can be dampened to values that won’t harm your electronics.

The surge protector takes the hit and absorbs the spike protecting other electronic equipment.

Since you have a known issue I would recommend a large system as the active components in a surge suppressor (MOV’s or metal oxide varistors) will fail quickly if undersized a larger system can last for years.

Basically a MOV dumps spikes over a threshold voltage to ground so your electronics don’t experience the high voltage and fail if the spikes are large the mov’s can fail but replacing a module is a lot cheaper than a 5kv inverter.